# Regular expression to match specific number of digits

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression which returns a three digit integer only. Not less than three or more than three. However my regex below  is also true for four digit numbers. Am i missing something?

```
var threeDigits = /\d{3}$/

console.log(threeDigits.test("12"))// false
console.log(threeDigits.test("123"))// true
console.log(threeDigits.test("1234"))// true yet this is four digits???
```

Comment: You should use `^\d{3}$` where `^` is for start of string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have the ending anchor `$`, but not the starting anchor `^`:

```
var threeDigits = /^\d{3}$/
```

Without the anchor, the match can start anywhere in the string, e.g.

```
"1234".match(/\d{3}$/g)  // ["234"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use either one ^[0-9]{3}$ or ^\d{3}$ .